# css for the first direct child only

Tags: html, css

I have the following html structure:

```
<div class="nav-collapse">
              <ul class="nav">

              </ul>

              <ul id="registerCart" class="nav pull-right">

              </ul>

</div>
```

and I wanted to apply the following rule only to the first nav, so I did:

```
.nav-collapse > .nav {
    left: 135px;
}
```

however this is applying to the registerCart as well. How do I apply this only to the first nav?

Comment: Use this: `.nav-collapse > .nav:first-child` or assign a unique class to the first nav child element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the first child selector:

```
.nav-collapse .nav:first-child {}
```

You can combine it with the direct child selector if you have more nested `.nav` elements.

```
.nav-collapse > .nav:first-child {}
```

Answer (score 1):

The > operator means that it will select only the matching children that are a direct child (thus one level deep)  of the defined parent, instead of matching all children on all levels from the defined parent.

Using :first-child is perfectly ok but some problems could arise in IE7 and IE8 when dynamic content is involved. See http://www.quirksmode.org/css/selectors for known issues. When in doubt, select the first child by it's class or id attribute.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the class 'nav' to 'nave' it works as is! I suspect 'nav' is a reserved word.