# css change color after particular HTML tag

Tags: html, css

I am not better in CSS. I have to change the font color after particular tag. Eg.

```
<div class='showContent'>
    <ul>
    <li><span style='color:green;'><strong>Advantages</strong</span><strong>my title :</strong> My message </li> <!-- i should not change this because <strong> tag is not next to <li> tag , here <span> tag comes next to <li> -->
    <li><strong>my title :</strong> My message </li> <!-- i should change this title <strong> tag color because this comes next to <li> tag -->
    <li><strong>My title1 : </strong> My message my message <strong>My message in bold</strong> my message again </li>
    <li><span style='color:red;'>Disadvantages</span><strong>my title :</strong> My message </li>
    <li><strong>My title1 : </strong> My message my message <strong><a href=''>My message in bold</a></strong> my message again </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

So what is my requirement is here that i have to change all the `'<strong>my title</strong>'` to some color only which comes next to `<li> tags` Not in any other places

So i wrote in css

```
.showContent li strong:first-line
{
   color : blue;
}
```

but it is not changing.

Comment: try this if it's work `.showContent li strong:first-child { color: blue; }`

Comment: So you want `<li><strong>` to be blue but not `<li>some text <strong>`?

Comment: Is this the desired look of the end result: http://jsfiddle.net/5ftnN/.  I'm not intending this as an asnwer due to my inline styles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To only change color on direct first childs.

**Try this:**

```
.showContent ul li > strong:first-child {
   color : blue;
}
```

> The > operator means that it will select only the matching children
>   that are a direct child (thus one level deep) of the defined parent,
>   instead of matching all children on all levels from the defined
>   parent.

**[Credits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19764781/3739658)**

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2VN78/2/)**

Thanks to @MiljanPuzović

Comment: Updated the answer, according to your needs!

Comment: it changes all the strong tag color , please read my question i should change only the strong tag  which comes next to li tag not any where in the middle.

Comment: Did you see the updated answer? The second part answers your question :)

Comment: In your question on the title part... you are closing the `span` tag

Comment: the 'Advantages' also changed into blue color , it should be in green color only.

Comment: **.showContent ul li > strong:first-child**, this will affect <strong> tags that are only direct first childes of <li> tag

Comment: @Raaga Updated the answer for you!

Comment: @imbondbaby & Miljan Puzovic it works for me. Thanks to both of them

Answer (score 1):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/458aR/)

```
ul li strong
{
  color: red;
}
```

It will change all strong tags that is placed under li.

**[Another Demo]**(http://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/458aR/2/)

If you want to change only first strong tag , u can use this

```
ul li strong:nth-of-type(1)
{
  color: red;
}
```

**[Another way]**(http://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/458aR/4/)

```
ul li strong:first-child
{
  color: red;
}
```

If you want to change all the strong tags that comes under 'showContent', U have to prepend all the the above css with .showContent

Comment: The above suggestions is not working for me . if i apply it changes color of all the strong tag under showContent class

Comment: Have you checked another two demo's

Answer (score 0):

You can use the first-child attribute to set an color of the first element strong, ex:

```
strong:first-child{
   color: blue;
}
```

see more: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
.showContent ul li strong
{
    color: red;
}
```

You can look demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/458aR/).

Answer (score 0):

Then you can try like this: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/N7Smm/3/)**

**CSS:**

```
ul li span + strong
{
    color: blue;
}
ul li strong
{
    color: #c47400;
}
```

Comment: check your demo 'My message in bold also changed to brown color'

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to approach this from a different angle.

You are talking about *My Title* suggets a heading of some sort, so maybe use an `hx` tag instead. An alternate would be to use a span with a "title" class.

[Using an h3 tag](http://jsfiddle.net/WGjGm/1/)

```
<div class='showContent'>
    <ul>
    <li><span style='color:green;'>Advantages</span><h3>my title :</h3> My message </li>
    <li><h3>my title :</h3> My message </li>
    <li><h3>My title1 : </h3> My message my message <strong>My message in bold</strong> my message again </li>
    <li><span style='color:red;'>Disadvantages</span><h3>my title :</h3> My message </li>
    <li><h3>My title1 : </h3> My message my message <strong><a href=''>My message in bold</a></strong> my message again </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.showContent ul h3
{
    font-weight:bold;
    display:inline;
    color:blue;
    font-size:1em;
}

.showContent ul *+h3
{
    color:inherit;
}
```

Comment: i like your different way of approach but i don't have permission to change <strong> tag into <h3> tag . This is my client requirement. These contents are coming directly from the database.

Comment: I really hope your database it atleast outputting Title and Message seperately! Otherwise it could be interesing for you in the future.

Comment: If you do get a bit of room to move with the design of the HTML aim for something like: http://jsfiddle.net/WGjGm/2/. It gives you a lot more flexability:http://jsfiddle.net/WGjGm/3/, http://jsfiddle.net/WGjGm/4/  ..differences in CSS only.